# Sequence in $\ell_p$ spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, lp-spaces, examples-counterexamples

The sequence given by:
$$x_n=(1^{-1/q},2^{-1/q}-1^{-1/q}, 3^{-1/q}-2^{-1/q}, \dots)$$
That is,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1/q}-(n-1)^{-1/q}$$

Is this sequence in the sequence space $\ell_p$ ? where for $1<p< \infty$ and $q>1$:

$$\ell_p= \left \{ \left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathbb{R} \colon \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left | x_k \right |^p <\infty\right \}$$

Comment: Hint: $(n-1)^{-1/q} \sim n^{-1/q} - n^{-1 - 1/q}/q$ as $n \to \infty$.